# TeamCity: Unmet Requirements DotNetFramework4.[56]

Tags: .net, teamcity, .net-4.7

We've just installed .NET Framework 4.7.1 on our build agents, however our projects are now showing as having no compatible build agents.

Each agent is showing:

> Unmet requirements: Exists=>DotNetFramework4.[56](.[0-9]+)?_(x86|x64)
>   exists

We've followed [these instructions](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206201409-How-to-resolve-this-unmet-agent-requirement-DotNetFramework4-0-x86-exists-), however it didn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by an xUnit build step, where there was a bug in the xUnit TeamCity plugin that incorrectly reported that build agents that only had .NET 4.7+ installed were not compatible with the project.

The fix was to simply update the [xUnit TeamCity plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8909-xunit-test-runner) which contains the bug fix, and the relevant projects started building successfully again.